# Blender needs more CPU power than before

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I haven't done much I only moved the Camera, the smoke meshes and increased the size of the smoke domain. And now the render needs much more time than before.

And what can I do before the render that it doesn't need so much time.

Comment: Rendering smoke takes time.  Keep in mind that rendering more smoke from a bigger domain will necessarily take more time than a smaller domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79117/why-does-fire-take-so-long-to-render?rq=1

Comment: Are you simply asking it to do more work?